# Best way to test for FOO or BAR or Foo or Bar in a regex?

Tags: regex, capitalization

I am doing checking for keywords which are headers, and the input is totally out of my control.

So I've figured out that they will have the first letter capitalized, but also might be in all caps.

I can do a Java Pattern that is:

```
Pattern test = Pattern.compile("\\b(FOO|BAR|Foo|Bar)\\b");
```

And doing a Pattern matcher with that works fine.  As in:

```
boolean ans = test.matcher(sometext).find();
```

However when I have 6 or 8 keywords to check for it starts to get kind of ugly to have all the keywords there twice.

Can anyone come up with a more elegant regex that might do this?

Thanks

ADDED 3/26/15

Let me re-emphasize, its not as simple as just ignoring case completely, which is what was initially suggested.  The first letter does need to be capitalized, its the rest of the string that can be upper or lower.

Comment: Most regex engines have an 'i' option for 'ignorecase' - I bet Java does too, but I don't know what it would be precisely. That would match too much (e.g. fOo) but is that a problem? [Edit: maybe `Pattern test = Pattern.compile("\\b(foo|bar)\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);`]

Comment: Once you compile the pattern, it isn't really a problem that there are many traversal paths through the generated state machine (unless we are talking millions, so that you could run out of memory). For convenience, you might want to generate the pattern from a list of strings programmatically, just because that makes the code easier to maintain (debugging a typo in a complex regex is daunting).

Answer (score 0):

Use the "ignore case" flag `(?i)`:

```
Pattern test = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\b(FOO|BAR)\\b");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `\\b\\b` since anything that comes normally is treated as a word rather than as acharacter class.

also use `i`(ignoreCase) modifier.

Your regex should be:

```
(foo|bar)
```

Add, `i` modifier, according to your language

Also, you are saying "to test". Using regex for that is overkill.

Do this:

```
String Str = new String("Welcome to Foo bar ");
Str = Str.toLowerCase();
return Str.contains("foo")||Str.contains("bar"); // returns true or false
```